# What's the best way to detect on client side any changes to any fields of a rails 3.2 form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have an ajax link_to embedded in a simple_form and I need to check and display message asking user to save form first if the form is dirty.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@thing) do |f| %>

    <%= f.title %>

    # many other form fields #

    <%= f.button :submit %>

    <%= link_to 'Publish', publish_thing_path(@thing), method: :put, remote: true %>

<% end %>
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a jquery plugin called Are you sure

It's super simple and if I detect dirty I either submit for them or ask the user to verify info and submit.

https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks very much for the reference.  Will check it out!